# ios scratch card effect crash

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics

I need to use a scratch effect for my game. here is an example code years ago.

https://github.com/oyiptong/CGScratch

It works just fine, but when i use it together with navigation controller, it crashes.

My project uses ARC, i flag the file as -fno-objc-arc. Here is the source code:

https://github.com/lifesaglitch/ScratchWithError

it crashes when i push the view controller, then pop, then reenter.

Edit:

When you convert all to arc, and flag the view controller that uses the scratch view as -fno-objc-arc, it works. But when you flag the scratch view as -fno-objc-arc instead, it crashes again. My project uses arc and i dont think i can convert my own view controller to be -fno-objc-arc.

Edit 2:

I modify the initialization code to:

```
    scratchable = CGImageRetain([UIImage imageNamed:@"scratchable.jpg"].CGImage);
```

it does not crash anymore, but there's a memory leak. and CGImageRelease did get called once in dealloc method.

Comment: Without the crash log or report from the consul it is impossible to say how to fix the code so it won't  crash, unless someone has a crystal ball.

Comment: @CodeMonkey trust me, some times app crash without logs

Comment: That is logical, but the code you have posted is fine, unless you can recreate the crash and see the log it is almost impossible to pin point where the issue is.

Comment: @CodeMonkey im trying, but this time my simulator is just hanging. can you make a simple project? It's really simple. I've provided the download link. I just push a controller, pop it then re-push

Comment: I see nothing fundamentally wrong in the code you posted, nor in the project on github.  My guess is that you're not properly managing memory, which is easy to do, especially if you're mixing ARC, and MRC.  I would recommend just taking a few minutes to modify the "old" scratchable view code to make it ARC-compliant, and use ARC for your whole project.

Comment: @Nate hi, the github project works when theres only one viewcontroller. if you use navigation controller and push the controller with scratch views, pop it, then repush it, it crashes

Comment: @CodeMonkey please refer to the above reply

Comment: @OMGPOP, then I would recommend that you add a sample project that pushes, pops, and pushes a view controller, that demonstrates the crash.  Put it back on github if you like.  If other people can run your code, and see the problem, it'll be easier for you to get help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `CGImageCreateCopy`.

The reason for this is that you send a release to your `CGImageRef` at your `dealloc`, but if you inspect the actual `CGImage` object you'll see that it points to the *same memory address* each time (I guess it's part of Apple's optimizations, so it's just like you would have a `static UIImage` object and reference its `CGImage`).

So in your `initWithFrame:` you should get your scratchable like this:

```
UIImage *sci = [UIImage imageNamed:@"scratchable.jpg"]; // This guy is always the same
scratchable = CGImageCreateCopy(sci.CGImage);
```

**PS:** You had an actual leak with `pixels`, so you also need a `CFRelease(pixels);`

I tested, analyzed and measured the code and it seems to be OK now.

[Here is also a link to the fixed project](http://cl.ly/3K2X2g3w1244) (I've also put a navigation controller and a button to push/pop) - and uses ARC of course.

Answer (score 1):

This one works great for me https://github.com/moqod/iOS-Scratch-n-See !

Answer (score 0):

In AppDelegate.m

```
   [window addSubview:viewController.view];
```

You should instead replace it with:

```
   [window setRootViewController:viewController];
```